# Is it possible for a bot to detect if the user that joined has a new discord account? (JS)

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

So I wanted to make a discord bot that detects if the user that joined has a new discord account. When someone has this and you click on their profile, Clyde will be there and says 'Hi, I am new to discord.'
Is there a way to detect this? And if there is I also want to send a message in a specific channel.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the timestamp of the account: `<User>.createdTimestamp()`, and then substract this timestamp from `(new Date()).getTime()`. Then if the result is lesser than some time in ms, during which an account counts as `recently joined`.